# Java itext can't create pdf under windows, on ubuntu works fine

Tags: java, windows, itext

I have

```
public class Pdf {

    private static float FONTSIZE = 8;


    public void open(String filename) throws Exception
    {
        /*
        File f = new File(PATH + filename);
        if(f.exists() == true)
        {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("gnome-open " + PATH + filename);
            //Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler C:/pdf/test.pdf"); // WINDOWS
        }
        else
        {
            init(filename);
        }
        */
        init(filename +".pdf");
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("gnome-open " + Config.PATH + filename +".pdf");
    }

    public void init(String filename) throws Exception
    {
        Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4);
        doc.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);

        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream(Config.PATH + filename));

        doc.open();
        doc.addTitle("incasation");

        PdfPTable header = new PdfPTable(5);
        float[] widths = {5.6f, 6, 8, 5, 5};
        header.setWidths(widths);
        header.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        header.setWidthPercentage(100);
        header.setSpacingAfter(4);

        header.addCell(cell("Data: 20.04.2011", 0));
        PdfPCell pkt = cell("Punct de lucru: COM COM COM COM COM COM COM COM COM COM COM COM COM COM COM", 0);
            pkt.setColspan(2);
        header.addCell(pkt);
        PdfPCell cmp = cell("Company: SC ANC CNE", 0);
            cmp.setColspan(2);
        header.addCell(cmp);    
        PdfPCell pdate = cell("Ultima incasare: 06.03.2011", 0);

        header.addCell(pdate);
        header.addCell(cell("Zona: ADAAA", 0));
        header.addCell(cell("Operator: SOME ONE SPECIAL", 0));
        header.addCell(cell("Procent locatie: 45%", 0));
        header.addCell(cell("Metoda de plata: cash", 0));

        doc.add(header);

        Image img = Image.getInstance(Config.PATH +"tabelka.png");
        img.scalePercent(25, 25);


        // ON TOP
        PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
        BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, "Cp1250", false);
        cb.setFontAndSize(bf, FONTSIZE);
        cb.beginText();     

        float x = doc.getPageSize().getHeight() - 4;

        float start = x;
        int j = 0;

        for(int i=0; i< 5; i++)
        {           
            j++;
            if(i > 0 && i % 5 == 0)
            {
                cb.endText();
                doc.newPage();

                cb = writer.getDirectContent();
                cb.setFontAndSize(bf, FONTSIZE);
                cb.beginText();

                start = x;
                j = 1;
            }
            doc.add(img);


            cb.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, "0305/HS", 75, start- 53, 0);
            cb.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, "VUKA-HS-025", 75, start - 67.5f, 0);

            // ELEC
            // IN
            cb.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_RIGHT, "000001", 293, start - 67.5f, 0);
            cb.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_RIGHT, "000003", 365, start - 67.5f, 0);
            cb.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_RIGHT, "000002", 440, start - 67.5f, 0);

            // OUT
            cb.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_RIGHT, "000001", 293, start - 82, 0);
            cb.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_RIGHT, "000003", 365, start - 82, 0);
            cb.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_RIGHT, "000002", 440, start - 82, 0);

            // SUM
            cb.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, "0.50", 465, start - 73.5f, 0);     
            cb.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_RIGHT, "999.0", 565, start - 73.5f, 0);

            // MECH
            // IN
            cb.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_RIGHT, "000001", 293, start - 110, 0);
            cb.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_RIGHT, "000003", 365, start - 110, 0);
            cb.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_RIGHT, "000002", 440, start - 110, 0);

            // OUT
            cb.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_RIGHT, "000001", 293, start - 124, 0);
            cb.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_RIGHT, "000003", 365, start - 124, 0);
            cb.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_RIGHT, "000002", 440, start - 124, 0);

            // SUM
            cb.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, "0.50", 465, start - 115.5f, 0);        
            cb.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_RIGHT, "999.0", 565, start - 115.5f, 0);

            /// COINS AND NOTES
            cb.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_RIGHT, "0.5", 156, start - 82, 0);
            cb.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_RIGHT, "1", 156, start - 95.5f, 0);
            cb.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_RIGHT, "5", 156, start - 110, 0);
            cb.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_RIGHT, "10", 156, start - 124, 0);
            cb.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_RIGHT, "50", 156, start - 138, 0);
            cb.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_RIGHT, "100", 156, start - 152, 0);

            // COMMENTS
            cb.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, "comments...", 205, start - 138.5f, 0);

            start = (x - (img.getHeight() * 0.25f) * j);
        }
        //doc.add(content);
        cb.endText();
        // END

        PdfPTable footer = new PdfPTable(5);
        footer.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        footer.setWidthPercentage(100);

        footer.addCell(cell("Total sum: 3397.50", 0));
        footer.addCell(cell("Total pierderi: 0.00", 0));
        footer.addCell(cell("Total taxa: 0.00", 0));
        footer.addCell(cell("Baza de calcul: 3397.50", 0));
        footer.addCell(cell("Locatie: 1528.88", 0));

        PdfPCell b = cell("Num. de ordine al primului bilet: 0", 0);
            b.setColspan(2);
        footer.addCell(b);
        footer.addCell(cell("Num. de tichete: 0", 0));
        footer.addCell(cell("Corectie tichete: 0", 0));
        footer.addCell(cell("Total bilete: 0.00", 0));

        PdfPCell b1 = cell("Num de ordine al ultimului bilet: 0", 0);
            b1.setColspan(3);
        footer.addCell(b1);

        PdfPCell t = cell("Bani ce trebuiesc viratii: 18.441", 0);
            t.setColspan(2);
        footer.addCell(t);

        PdfPCell s = cell("Suma de bani platita: de clienti", 0);
            s.setColspan(5);
        footer.addCell(s);

        PdfPCell o = cell("Obs: ", 0);
            o.setColspan(5);
        footer.addCell(o);
        doc.add(footer);

        PdfContentByte cb1 = writer.getDirectContent();
        BaseFont bf1 = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, "Cp1250", false);
        cb1.setFontAndSize(bf1, FONTSIZE);
        cb1.beginText();    

        cb1.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_RIGHT, "Semnatura Reprezentant Firma", 130, start - 210, 0);
        cb1.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, "Semnatura & Stampila Reprezentant", 500, start - 210, 0);
        cb1.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, "Pemct de lucru", 500, start - 220, 0);
        cb1.endText();
        // CLOSE
        doc.close();
    }

    public PdfPCell cell(String txt, int border)
    {
        Font font = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, FONTSIZE);
        Paragraph p = new Paragraph(txt, font);
            p.setSpacingAfter(0);
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(p);
        cell.setBorder(border);
        return cell;
    }

}
```

I have export my project to jar, then compile it to exe on windows and pdf dont work. Class create file pdf with 0kb. 
What can be wrong ?

Comment: Your title is confusing?  Does it work on the command line? Is there an exception? It sounds like you need some debugging.

Comment: Title changed forgot about "t" in "cant" word

Comment: So, does running the application on the console work on both Windows and Ubuntu?  Does the jar work on both?  Is it just the exe running on windows that has the problem?

Comment: Problem solved i dont know why but `dir.getAbsolutePath()` gives the directory with dot at the end so the file should be .tabelka.png not tabelka.png

Comment: Put your finding as answer and accept it. So that others a few months/years later may use your knowledge.